# drupal_add_js() won't work with footer scope

Tags: 7, javascript

i 'm trying to add a file to end of body via template.php in mytheme_preprocess_page.
this is the line i have:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/js/file.js',array('type' => 'file','scope' => 'footer'));
```

why i can't see file.js in view source? -if i change footer scope to header file.js add to head tag -

[doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) says:

> Possible values are 'header' or 'footer'. If your theme implements
>   different regions, you can also use these

i tried to add footer region to page.tpl.php but it doesn't work.

what do means footer scope?

Comment: Are you printing $page_top, $page, $page_bottom in html.tpl.php? I think in D7 'footer' falls under $page_bottom in html.tpl.php, but I could be wrong.

Comment: thank you. you are right. i was missing $page_bottom. i find this drupal.org/update/themes/6/7#closure now. if you add answer i will accept your answer  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're printing `$page_bottom` in `html.tpl.php`.

In Drupal 6, it looked like this:

```
<?php print $closure; ?>
```

In Drupal 7, you now want all 3 of the `$page_top`, `$page`, and `$page_bottom` variables which correlate to the `header`, `content`, and `footer` scopes. Here's a sample (and simple) `html.tpl.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<body>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```